# Child component re-renders before local storage is cleared

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a small restaurant app which renders a menu and lets users place an order. The parent component receives an array of menu items and renders a child component for each item. The quantity of each item is initialized at the child component ('menu-item') and is also saved in local storage so if a user refreshes the page the order persists. Once the order is submitted, local storage is cleared by the parent component but this change is not picked up by the child. As a result, users see the order quantity even after the order has been submitted. I would like the order quantity to be reset to 0 after the order is submitted. Below is the condensed codebase.

//Parent

```
const TotalStore = {
  total: 0,
  reset_timer: setTimeout(() => {}, 0),
  compute() {
    let newTotal = 0;
    let types = new Map<string, boolean>();
    TotalStore.items.forEach((value: TotalStoreMenuItem) => {
      newTotal += value.price * value.count;
      types.set(value.type, true);
    });

    if (TotalStore.total !== newTotal) {
      clearTimeout(TotalStore.reset_timer);
      TotalStore.reset_timer = setTimeout(() => {
        TotalStore.total = newTotal;
        TotalStore.onChange(newTotal);
      }, 50);
    }
  },
  update(id: number, price: number, count: number, type: string) {
    TotalStore.items.set(id, {
      id,
      price,
      count,
      type,
    });
    TotalStore.compute();
  },
  reset() {
    TotalStore.items.clear();
    localStorage.clear();
    TotalStore.total = 0;
  },
  onChange(t: number) {},
  items: new Map<number, TotalStoreMenuItem>(),
};
```

```
const itemChanged = (
    id: number,
    price: number,
    count: number,
    type: string
  ) => {
    TotalStore.update(id, price, count, type);
  };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    apiFetch("menu").then((json) => setMenu(json.menu));
  }, []);
```

```
async function handleSubmit(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selectedItems = getSelectedItems(TotalStore);
    apiFetch("order", "post", { selectedItems })
      .then((json) => {
        alert("Order has been submitted");
        TotalStore.reset();
}
```

```
return (
    <div>
      {menu.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <div className="menu">
            <div className="menu-title">Food Menu</div>
            <form id="menu-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
              <Menu onChange={itemChanged} props={menu} />
              <button type="submit" disabled={!orderPlaced(total)}>
                Place Order
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="order-total">
            <h2>
              Total: $<span>{total.toFixed(2)}</span>
            </h2>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>Loading Menu</>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

//Menu

```
export default function Menu({ onChange, props }: MenuProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.map((food: any, index: number) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem
            key={index}
            onChange={onChange}
            type={food.type}
            item={food}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

//Menu-Item

```
const FoodItemLocalStore = {
  setCount(id: Number, count: Number) {
    localStorage.setItem(`menu_item_id_${id}`, String(count));
  },
  getCount(id: Number) {
    return parseInt(localStorage.getItem(`menu_item_id_${id}`) || "0");
  },
};

export default function MenuItem({ onChange, item, type }: MenuItemProps) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    count: FoodItemLocalStore.getCount(item.id),
  });

  const menuItemCountChange = (e: any) => {
    data.count = parseInt(e.target.value);
    FoodItemLocalStore.setCount(item.id, data.count);
    setData({ ...data });
  };

  onChange(item.id, item.price, data.count, type);

  return (
    <div>
      <article className="menu-item" data-item-type={type}>
        <h3 className="item-name">{item.name}</h3>
        <input
          type="number"
          className="menu-item-count"
          min="0"
          value={data.count}
          onChange={menuItemCountChange}
        />
        <strong className="item-price">${item.price.toFixed(2)}</strong>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I recommend you not naming one of your props to `props`, it is confusing.

Comment: The Parent fetches the menu array from the server and its then passed to Menu as props={menu}. I guess Menu component isn't really needed as we can do menu.map to render Menu-Item. This would make the code more concise but it doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: Start by removing localStorage and put the state in useState instead. This will make sure that your UI updates whenever you set the new state. Update the code in the question when you are done and Ill show you how to add so that it can handle refresh

Comment: I assume you are referring to this state:
`const [data, setData] = useState({ count: FoodItemLocalStore.getCount(item.id), }); ` 
in the Menu-Item component.
If we remove local storage how can we persist the user order when the browser is refreshed?